# Get column results from DataTable into a string

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a select statement that returns data to a DataTable. About 3-5 columns and 5-10 rows. I'm trying to collect all the data from the "Email" Column and add it to a single-line string.

| Email | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Why@aol.com | frank | 213-444-1911 |
| Sit@aol.com | shawn | 213-444-1092 |
| Wow@aol.com | chloe | 213-444-1229 |
| Who@aol.com | shane | 213-444-1769 |

Result:

> Why@aol.com;Sit@aol.com;Wow@aol.com;Who@aol.com

Comment: Need more information on the environment being used. If there is any [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object–relational_mapping) or at least what type of variable is holding the data after the database returns.

Comment: The most basic way to achieve is to create a variable to hold the `output` then loop through the rows and concat the email column into the `output` variable with the `;` character at the end of each concatenation. **But without knowing the environment, can't suggest any code.**

Comment: if you are using database query/stored proc then you can get comma separated values from there only.

Comment: The data is returned to DataTable dtGetInfo = new DataTable(); no stored peocedures or anything.

Comment: I tried a variable and a foreach loop but it would give me the whole row. I just need the column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

1. Iterate each `DataRow` and get the value from `DataColumn`.
2. Add value into array/list.
3. Convert array/list to string with `String.Join()` with `;` as separator.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> emails = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    emails.Add(row["Email"].ToString());
}

string result = String.Join(";", emails);
```

---

**Solution 2**

1. Working with **System.Linq** to get the email as `List<string>`.
2. Convert array/list to string with `String.Join()` with `;` as separator.

```cs
using System.Linq;

string result = String.Join(";", dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(x => x["Email"].ToString())
                                      .ToList());
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CurBRW)